# How to remove rounded corners from one jQuery UI widget but not the others?

Tags: jquery-ui

My particular problem is that I want the autocomplete function to not have round corners, but all the other widgets that have round corners should.
Is there a parameter I can pass to disable the corners just for the autocomplete?

**Edit**

Let's see if this can be answered.

On page *[Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline)*.

I'd like to remove all round-corner classes from appearing (the header and the next-previous buttons).

`$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker('widget').removeClass('ui-corner-all');` would not work.

Answer (score 12):

Very late but here it goes:

jQuery UI widgets have a method, which returns the HTML node for the widget itself.
So the answer would be:

```
$('#someinput').autocomplete(...).autocomplete('widget').removeClass('ui-corner-all');
```

**Responding to the EDIT:**

As far I can see, you need to chain `widget()` method with `autocomplete()` (or `datepicker()`) method for it to work. Seems like it doesn't work for regular HTML nodes returned by `$()`.

Comment: Great! +1 Thanks for discover to me:
.removeClass('ui-corner-all'); applies to a few widgets :)

Answer (score 6):

assign this css class to the element with corners of your widget.

```
.ui-corner-flat {
    border-top-left-radius: 0px !important;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px !important;
}

$("#elementwithcorners").addClass("ui-corner-flat");
```

Comment: shorter one: border-radius: 0px !important;

Answer (score 3):

to remove the bottom left radius

in the constructor I did this

```
    $( "#signup" ).dialog(
        {
            create: function (event, ui) {

                $(".ui-dialog").css('border-bottom-left-radius','0px');
            },

        }
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

The `_suggest()` method of the Autocomplete widget calls `menu.refresh()`, and therefore resets the `ui-corner-all` class for menu items, etc., each time the input changes. However, the `open()` callback is called after every `menu.refresh()` call within `_suggest()`, and so is a sensible place to adjust classes as desired:

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete("option", {
  open: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).autocomplete("widget")
           .menu("widget").removeClass("ui-corner-all")
           .find(".ui-corner-all").removeClass("ui-corner-all");
  }
});
```

The Datepicker widget is a little tougher, as it's built to be sort of a semi-singleton. Here we need a monkey patch to do it consistently, since none of the supplied callback options is suitable:

```
// store the built-in update method on the "global" instance...
$.datepicker.__updateDatepicker = $.datepicker._updateDatepicker;
// ...and then clobber with our fix
$.datepicker._updateDatepicker = function(inst) {
  $.datepicker.__updateDatepicker(inst);
  inst.dpDiv.removeClass("ui-corner-all")
      .find(".ui-corner-all").removeClass("ui-corner-all");
};
```

Note that the default `_updateDatepicker()` implementation has no return value. Also, note that the `_updateDatepicker()` method is *not* an interface method, so should not be assumed to be available. As such, the most consistent way to accomplish the corner fix is with appropriate CSS, along the lines of:

```
.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu.ui-corner-all,
.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu .ui-menu-item > a.ui-corner-all,
.ui-datepicker.ui-corner-all,
.ui-datepicker-header.ui-corner-all,
.ui-datepicker-next.ui-corner-all,
.ui-datepicker-prev.ui-corner-all {
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

More specificity (or the `!important` directive) may be used to ensure these selectors are respected. This is exactly why jQuery uses theme classes – fudging these things in is an interesting hack, but it's the less clean option unless style is unavailable…

Answer (score 1):

Create a new CSS class for the element you don't want rounded corners.

```
p.rounded { border-radius: 10px; }
```

`p.none-rounded { border-radius: 0; }`

Comment: Thanks, but the question is related to controlling the actual jQuery UI without changing css stylesheets